# Next and prev not working with angular2-Materialize carousel

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I want to move from slide to slide using the next and prev functions. I can't use JQuery so '$' is not an option. I added a [materializeActions] attribute to to my carousel and setup the event emitter in my component. I know something is working a little because when I call "actions.emit('next') I don't get an error; however, when I call "actions.emit('badFunc') I do get an error.

This code is from the sample that is provided with angular2-materialize. All I added was a button to move next.

```
<div #carousel class="carousel" [ngClass]="{ 'initialized': showInitialized }"  materialize="carousel" [materializeActions]="actions">
<a *ngFor="let url of imageURLs" class="carousel-item"><img [src]="url"></a>
</div> 

<button (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

Code from the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  public modules: IModule[];

  @ViewChild('carousel') carouselElement;
  actions = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {

  }

 imageURLs = [
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1264645/364153082/stock-photo-asian-girl-in-sunflower-field-364153082.jpg',
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1264645/298927574/stock-photo-a-young-traveler-girl-sit-on-the-wooden-bridge-in-halong-bay-and-enjoy-the-beauty-of-seascape-298927574.jpg',
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1264645/298757792/stock-photo-a-young-traveler-girl-sit-on-the-top-of-mountain-in-halong-bay-and-enjoy-the-beauty-of-seascape-298757792.jpg',
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2565601/411902890/stock-photo-ha-long-bay-scenic-view-hanoi-vietnam-411902890.jpg',
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2565601/413207668/stock-photo-the-temple-of-literature-in-hanoi-vietnam-the-chinese-words-is-poem-of-thie-temple-and-templs-s-413207668.jpg'
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

     // example of a hacky way to add an image to the carousel dynamically
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.imageURLs = [this.imageURLs[0], ...this.imageURLs]; // duplicate the first iamge
      this.carouselElement.nativeElement.classList.toggle('initialized');
      this.actions.emit('carousel');
    }, 1000);
  }

  next() {

    // Move to next slide. This is not working
    this.actions.emit('next');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It needs to look like this:

```
this.actions.emit({ action: 'carousel', params: ['next'] });
this.actions.emit({ action: 'carousel', params: ['prev'] });
```